# Macro with conditionals inside label

Tags: macros, conditionals, labels

I'd like a label to be defined by a macro which value depends on some conditions. The aim is to obtain automatically a label of the type `fig:03` or `fig:03+04` or `fig:03+04+05`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\def\imga{03}
\def\imgb{04}
\def\imgc{}

\newcommand{\multipiclabel}{%
\imga%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\imgb}{}}{}{+}\imgb%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\imgc}{}}{}{+}\imgc%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption / \protect\multipiclabel}
  \label{fig:\multipiclabel}% this gives error
%  \label{fig:\imga+\imgb+\imgc}% this works but may define label with unwanted trailing +
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

but the above MWE does not compile.

Is there a way to define a label through a macro containing conditionals?

Comment: `\ifthenelse` is not expandable, so it can't go inside `\label`. Try `\ExplSyntaxOn
\newcommand{\multipiclabel}{%
\imga
\tl_if_empty:oTF{\imgb}{}{+}\imgb
\tl_if_empty:oTF{\imgc}{}{+}\imgc}
\ExplSyntaxOff`

Comment: Even if it's *possible* to define a `\label` along the lines you've laid out, it's still a *very bad idea*, typographically speaking. If you start messing with the arguments of `\label` in this way, you'll have to do so as well with the arguments of the various `\ref` statements. A fairly deep point of LaTeX's `\label`-`\ref` mechanism, which may need some contemplation before it can sink in, is that the arguments of `\label` and `\ref` (or `\autoref`, `\cref`, etc) are best viewed as abstract descriptions, e.g, `eq:euler` or `fig:mandelbrot`, and not as specific "numbers" or strings.

Comment: @Mico I don't know if it is a bad idea, but it's the only way to go for me, since I use a macro producing figures with a variable number of images, and this technique allows me to know in advance the label of a figure from the images it uses.

Comment: @mmj - I don't understand the relevance of the claim that "this technique allows me to know in advance the label of a figure from the images it uses". Why do you care whether a `\label`'s argument evaluates to `fig:03+04+05` or "just" `fig:03+04`? The label's complexity doesn't matter one bit when it comes to creating cross-references to the figure. (Remember that the figure's number is produced by `\caption`, not by `\label`.)

Comment: @Mico I should have explained that I use automatic labeling of figures based on images filenames (`03`, `04` and `05` are image filenames), so I don't have to choose the labels and I have to care only about references. I need to know in advance the labels so I can write references to figures.

Comment: generating the label in general is a bad idea, but labeling with the figure filename is perfectly reasonable, why don't you simply do that if that is the real use case?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That's what I'm doing, but in addition my macro accepts a variable number of images (from 1 to 4, using pgfkeys), the question arises from such a need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\multipiclabel` should be defined using primitive conditionals which are expandable:

```
\def\multipiclabel{\imga
   \ifx\imgb\empty\else +\imgb\fi \ifx\imgc\empty\else +\imgc\fi}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `#` is not used within definitions of `\imga`/`\imgb`/`\imgc` you can, e.g.,  do:

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\def\imga{03}
\def\imgb{04}
\def\imgc{}

\begingroup
\catcode`\#=8
\csname @firstofone\endcsname{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand*{\multipiclabel}{%
    \imga\if#\imgb#\else+\imgb\fi\if#\imgc#\else+\imgc\fi
  }%
}%

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure*}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{Caption / \protect\multipiclabel}
  \label{fig:\multipiclabel}%
\end{figure*}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

The .aux-file is:

```latex
\relax 
\@writefile{lof}{\contentsline {figure}{\numberline {1}{\ignorespaces Caption / \multipiclabel }}{1}{}\protected@file@percent }
\newlabel{fig:03+04}{{1}{1}}
\gdef \@abspage@last{1}
```

As you can see from the `\newlabel`-entry, the argument of the `\label`-command evaluates to `fig:03+04`.

---

If ε-TeX-extensions are available:

```latex
\newcommand*{\multipiclabel}{%
    \imga
    \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\imgb}$\else+\imgb\fi
    \ifcat$\detokenize\expandafter{\imgc}$\else+\imgc\fi
}%
```

With this definition `#` can be used within definitions of `\imga`/`\imgb`/`\imgc`—if you really want to use them, they need to be doubled within these definitions.

---

Although I actually like `\ifx` more I decided to have the test done in terms of `\if` or `\ifcat` because with `\ifx..\empty` it is relied on `\imgb`/`\imgc` always being defined as "short" macros like `\empty`. I am a pessimist: Some day somebody who read one of those many "introductions" to LaTeX where for no good reason one is told to never use `\def` but to always use LaTeX's `\newcommand`/`\renewcommand` might not use TeX's `\def` but LaTeX's `\renewcommand` (without `*` behind it) for defining `\imgb`/`\imgc` with the side-effect of those being `\long`-macros. Then we get another question of pattern "why doesn't it work"...

Comment: How would one make use of this approach to create a cross-reference to the figure with `\label{fig:\multipiclable}`? To make the question non-trivial, let's assume that `\label{fig:\multipiclable}` occurs at least twice. If one has to resort to `\ref{fig:03+04}` to create the cross-reference, what's the point in not writing `\label{fig:03+04}` to begin with?

Comment: @Mico I gave +1 to your two comments. I, too, think that the concept might not be the best. But that decision is the questioner's, not mine.  I assume that the questioner is willing to resort to explicitly typing `fig:03+04`  for referencing while for the corresponding `\label`-command  the phrase is created automatically by a macro whose arguments the questioner can see in the .tex-source and from whose arguments the questioner can easily conclude names of referencing-labels. As `\imga` etc denote numbers I assume ranges are passed with that macro for doing things in a loop.